# Can somebody please explain this pseudo code to me in terms of java code?

Tags: arrays, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

Here is the code for a BFS, I don't understand what this means in java code. terms like .pathlen, the arrows, etc I don't understand any of it. Can anyone clarify? thanks.

[Image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7GIg.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate through each vertex of graph g and mark a boolean as not visited.
2. Initialize a queue of vertices.
3. Mark and declare the starting node as visited.
4. Set the length of the path to the starting node as 0. This would be an integer field variable in the vertex class.
5. Add the first node to the queue.
6. While the queue is not empty, repeat the following.
7. Remove the head node from the queue.
8. For every edge that is adjacent to the vertex you removed, so you would go through the adjacency list or matrix on the graph and look for edges close to it.
9. If the node's boolean variable says that the edge's destination is not visited, then:
10. Add the edge's destination to the queue.
11. Mark the destination node from the edge as visited.
12. Add one to the length of the path on the edge's node, on top of the starting node's edge weight.

Note: If you have a weighted graph then you can do something other than +1 on step #12. But you shouldn't terminate the BFS until it runs on all nodes if you make it weighted.

Answer (score -1):

Pathlen is just a member variable. Think of that like the syntax for accessing a public variable of a java class.

The arrow syntax is a syntax for assignment, the equivalent of java's `=`. It means "Take the thing on the right and assign the thing on the left that value."